# Dropdown as a custom editor for object list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view that displays all the object's properties by using `ModelMetadata`:

```
  @foreach (var property in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties)
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label(property.PropertyName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.Editor(property.PropertyName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, Context = context })
                @Html.ValidationMessage(property.PropertyName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

But my Model has the next property:

```
[Required]
public virtual User Owner { get; set; }
```

It is supposed to show a dropdown with the list of users so I could select one.
I have added the following editor template at `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\User.cshtml`:

```
@using Views.Projects
@model Models.Users.User
@{
    Layout = null;
    var context = (ProjectContext) ViewData["Context"];
    var elements = new SelectList(context.AvailableUsers, Model);
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x, elements)
```

But the changes doesn't seem to apply - whatever user I select is not saved in the object and validation fails (because the Owner == null, and it is required)

How do I make this work?

*Update*

Raw html generated:

```
<div class="form-group"> 
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Owner">Owner</label> 
    <div class="col-md-10"> 
        <select id="Owner" name="Owner">
            <option>User1</option> 
            <option>User2</option>  
            <option>User3</option>     
        </select> 
     <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Owner" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span> 
     </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please share the names of fields that are generated corresponding to Owner/user's properties?

Comment: MVC already has this (`EditorForModel()` or `EditorFor(m => m)`)

Comment: @sachin Not sure I understand. My `Project` has `User Owner {get;set}`. `User` has bunch of properties like `string Name, string Initials`, but they are not important here.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yep. I'm using `Html.Editor(string)`, because it allows me to dynamically pick templates, but this is exactly the same as `Html.EditorFor(m => m)` as far as I understand

Comment: Can you share the name of DropDown that is being generated for Owner?

Comment: @sachin You mean raw html? Please see updated question

Comment: what I understood from your question is that you want everywhere you are using User property to show a drop down right? you can do the following => create User `EditorTemplate` in the shared EditorTemplates folder and mark `UIHint("User")` above the User Property underneath `[Required]`

Comment: @HadiHassan I've already created an editor template. My question is about how do I write it so it shows me the list of users

Comment: the elements should be passed through `ViewBag.Users` for example, and from the controller in any action that its view displays the dropdown, fill out the `ViewBag.Users`, shall I write an answer to show you the idea?

Comment: @HadiHassan That would be great. But please check the code I have posted, so you don't have to do unnecessary job. I'm trying already to do something like you describe, so maybe the answer can be simpler

Comment: just confirmation, the User object has an Id and displayname right? if so, then the value of Id should be returned and not the whole object, then your statement `new SelectList(context.AvailableUsers, Model);` should be changed to `new SelectList(context.AvailableUsers, "Id","displayname",Model.Id);`

Comment: @HadiHassan I've discussed the problem with sachin in a chat and he helped me. Thanks for your help

Comment: @HadiHassan The last parameter would be Model and not Model.Id because context.AvailableUsers is Collection of Model objects and not collection of Model.Ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use this for generating your DropDown in the `EditorTemplate` for `User`:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Name, elements)
```

or

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ID, elements)
```

The name of `Select` field has to point to one of the Unique properties of `User`(ID or Name whatever is the case). The model binder doesn't know which property of user to bind to if the Name of field is just `User` and not `User.ID` or `User.Name`.

Comment: If I do this, that will change the name in the User, but I want to change the whole User in the project. Or do I miss some important concept? I've just started working with MVC

Comment: Then bind dropdown to the ID of the user. The submitted User/Owner object would only have the ID, which should be used for linking User/Owner with the Model via foreign key or something.

Comment: That could work, but this is very unpleasant way to go. It will corrupt my model and will add a lot of additional code I wanted to avoid by using all these editors. It's weird that MVC cannot do things like that by itself. I just want to select one object as an editor for another one

Comment: It shouldn't corrupt your model in any way, your model would have the changed ID for the Owner, you may populate other properties by fetching User corresponding to that ID. The limitation is not with MVC, the generated HTML is only posting one property of the User and not the whole User object on form submission.

Comment: That's already a model corruption if I start to populate my objects with Id references instead of the real objects. I mean I do not want to have `item.UserId`, but rather `item.User`

Comment: It won't be item.UserId, it would be item.User.Id. May be you misunderstood. You don't need to have a separate UserId in your model.

Comment: I probably just miss the concept. can you write a short example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123532/discussion-between-sachin-and-archeg).